# Redshift query array<varchar(128)> returning encoded values

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We have an external table created in Redshift like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spectrum.my_table(
  insert_id varchar(128), 
  attribution_ids array<varchar(100)>
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  event_date varchar(128))
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION
  's3://my_bucket/my_path'
```

We do everything perfectly, but when we query the `array<varchar>` field as the documentation describes:

```
SELECT c.insert_id, a FROM 
    spectrum.my_table c, c.attribution_ids a LIMIT 10
```

Redshift return the `insert_id` correctly but the array it returns encoded please see below:

```
"insert_id",                            "o"
"0baed794-df11-4032-b13c-aac5d0deced7"  "0b8ad4fd9af12804ffaea83f4886672b"
```

The source data should be like:

```
"0baed794-df11-4032-b13c-aac5d0deced7", [0baed794-df11-4032-b13c-aac5d0deced7, 0baed794-df11-4032-b13c-aac5d0deced7]
```

When we run the same query in Athena running as a `SELECT * FROM my_table` it returns the array with the correct data.

What should I do here?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the source data.

Comment: What do you mean by _encoded_?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift does not support nested data types.

Redshift spectrum has simple support for nested data types - collection types like `array` or `map` has to be unnested (exploded) before selecting.

Unnesting basically does kind of a `CROSS JOIN` of all collection items with the row that collection belongs to.

Notice the syntax: `... FROM TABLE a, a.collecion_column B ...` - in classical queries that's the synonym for `CROSS JOIN`.

So what you are seeing in in `"o"` column is one of the items from `attribution_ids` array.

Comment: So, I tried to read that data, casting to varchar but it doesn't convert for the right type. What should I do?

Comment: So, are you saying that in the unnested column you're getting a `0b8ad4fd9af12804ffaea83f4886672b` and this value does not exist in the array? Is Athena giving you different result? Equivalent query would be `SELECT insert_id, a FROM 
    spectrum.my_table cross join  unnest(attribution_ids) as t(a)`